# Request an extension for paper revision

Tags: peer-review

The deadline for submitting my revised paper for a journal is July 30th. I emailed the editor and asked for the deadline in two weeks, but the editor did not respond. Where is the problem? Why didn't the editor answer? Is this common? I'm afraid the deadline will come and my request will be ignored and the article will be rejected. I would like your help.
I am sure the email address is correct and sent.

Comment: How long have you waited?  Editors are busy people.  I know of an Editor who only attends to his/her journal responsibilities one day a month.  You can try emailing the admin person for the journal.  In my experience, missing a deadline won't result in a rejection.  I had journals chase me after the deadline of my papers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Prof. ...  Among a week. In his previous email, the editor himself suggested that I have this option to request an extension.

Comment: Don't worry. I'm pretty sure the *worst case* scenario that can happen is the journal declining your manuscript with option to resubmit. That doesn't have any serious consequences. The editor would still send it to the same reviewers. If the journal declines it is because they care about their statistical benchmarks (time from submission to acceptance). They still would want to get the submission but prefer it as a new submission. But it's very likely that they will just grant the extension.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Ronald. Its alright. I'm not worried anymore.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: we are all humans, and the editor is probably aware if this, too. Hence, I believe that missing a deadline (in most cases) wont cause immediate rejection of a paper even if you had not asked for an extension.

As editors are commonly very busy, you should not put that much weight on him/her not responding within a week’s time. Furthermore, if you clearly requested an extension of the deadline to a new date X, you have fulfilled your obligation to request an extension. Therefore, under normal circumstances, I would assume that you are now on the safe side for the time being, although the editor did not yet respond.

Comment: Your answer was promising. So the reason for this is my inexperience. Thank you very much dear pbaer.